# Как обернуть каждое изображение в отдельный блок?

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема так как я не верно что то делаю.
Я хочу обернуть каждое изображение в div с любым именем class.

К примеру:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
```

Дальше я пишу в js вот так

```
let images = [...document.querySelectorAll("img")];

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'inset');

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){

}

body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

И в итоге тег inset оборачивает все изображения а надо обернуть так

```
<div class="inset"><img src="img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="inset"><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="inset"><img src="img3.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

То есть каждое изображение в отдельный div.inset

**Помогите разобраться**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'inset');
  wrapper.appendChild(img);
  document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
});
```

```css
.inset {
  border: 2px inset lightgreen;
  margin:2px;
  padding:4px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="AAA" />
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="BBB" />
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="CCC" />
```

Comment: `document.body` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body#Browser_compatibility

Comment: это получается мне надо было в цикле  создавать div, так ?

Comment: @aast4xov да *(3 символа нужно)*

Comment: @Igor какие три символа ?

Comment: @aast4xov, нельзя просто взять и написать да. коментарий не пройдёт по длинет

Comment: @aast4xov Слишком короткий комментарий.

Comment: @Igor понял ….просто точки тоже можно это тоже символ

Comment: @Igor, `Element.className` `Element.classList` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility `setAttribute('class')` затрёт ...